# Job scheduling algorithm with deadline and execution time

Tags: algorithm, job-scheduling, greedy

Given an array of jobs where every job has a deadline(d_i > 0) and associated execution time (e_i > 0), i.e. 
we have been given an array of (d_i, e_i) , can we find an arrangement of jobs such that all of them can be scheduled. There may be more than possible answer, any one will suffice.

e.g. {(3,1),(3,2),(7,3)} {J1,J2,J3}
Answer could be one of them {J1,J2,J3} or {J2,J1,J3}

We can solve this problem using backtracking but running time will be very high. Can we solve this problem using greedy or any other approach? Please provide it's correctness .

Edit:
At most one job can be run at a time .

Comment: Only one job can run at a time, correct?

Comment: @Mr.Llama yup , only one job.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: After you have scheduled k initial jobs successfully, it is possible to find a satisfying full schedule only if there is a next job whose execution time added to the current time after the k previous jobs is less than or equal to the deadline time for the next job. Can you see why always choosing the next job with the earliest deadline at each step of choosing a job will determine whether there is or is not a solution, and if there is, will give a precise solution? Let me know if you'd like more details about how to prove that, but hopefully you can see it on your own now that I've pointed out what the correct greedy solution is.

UPDATE: Further hint: Assume that you have a satisfying assignment where two consecutive jobs are out of order according to their deadlines (this just means the overall ordering of jobs is out of order somehow according to deadlines).  Then it is possible to finish both of these jobs before the earlier deadline of the two deadlines. Thus it is also possible to finish both jobs before the later deadline, by swapping the jobs, which will still be a satisfying assignment because by assumption you will now finish the earlier deadline job before the previous time you finished it, by assumption, and the later deadline of the two is later than the earlier deadline, and previously it was still possible to find a satisfying assignment.

Thus, if a satisfying assignment exists, then there is another one that exists where jobs are ordered according to their deadlines. I.e., the greedy strategy will always find a satisfying assignment if one exists -- otherwise, there is no solution.

Comment: I had the same solution , but can you provide some formal proof for 2nd part ( choosing earliest deadline is best choice ) .

Comment: @sonukumar Read this very nice article on matroids: http://jeremykun.com/2014/08/26/when-greedy-algorithms-are-perfect-the-matroid/

Comment: @sonukumar I updated my answer with an outline of why the greedy strategy will always work, otherwise there is no solution. Hopefully it is clear enough.

Comment: I really don't think this is true when profits are involved. I keep reading these proofs but it really isn't convincing me at all. I sent an example to my professor where ordering by deadline with non-unit (>1) times did not result in an optimal solution. I'm stuck on this totally in my homework and it's really depressing.

Answer (score 0):

A O(nlogn) Greedy approach based on heap data structure

---

the input is array of job

```
struct Job
{
char id;
int deadLine;
int  profit;
}
```

---

Algorithm pseudo code:

```
1.Sort the input jobArray in non-decresing order of deadLine.
2.create a maxHeap (will consists of job).Basis of Comparison is profit
3.let n=length of jobArray
      initialize time=jobArray[n-1].deadLine
                 index=n-1
4.while index>=0 && jobArray[index].deadLine >= time
        4a) insert(maxHeap,jobArray[index])
        4b) index=index-1
5. j=removeMax(maxHeap)
   print j.id
   time=time-1
6.if time > 0
     goto step 4.
else
     return ;
```

This will print jobs in the reverse order .
It can be modified to print in right order;